# Wrong result array_map function

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary

this is my input array...

```
$var = Array ( [0] => 57;5;7;Hertha BSC - SV Werder Bremen [1] => Heim )
```

I change it to another array with this function

```
$int_array = array_map("intval", explode(";", $var[0]));
```

When I call this array I get this result

```
Array ( [0] => 57 [1] => 5 [2] => 7 [3] => 0 )
```

But why is Array position [3] = 0. There must be "Hertha BSC..."?

Comment: What integer would you expect `Hertha BSC - SV Werder Bremen` to convert to?

Comment: Okay I understand the problem. This is only an array for int values. But how can I build an array for string to read the string value?

Comment: Don't use intval?

Comment: Give an example of the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

The description of the [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function, according to the PHP docs is:

> Get the integer value of a variable

The integer value of `Hertha BSC - SV Werder Bremen` (the 4th element of the array created by exploding `;` on `"57;5;7;Hertha BSC - SV Werder Bremen"`) is not clear.

Throwing a string at it will not yield meaningful results in this context. So, I don't think it's the *wrong* result.

Here's something that might get you a little closer to what I think you're after, though

```
$var = [
    '57;5;7;Hertha BSC - SV Werder Bremen',
    'Heim'
];

$int_array = array_map(
    function($item) {
        // In cases where the exploded array item is not entirely made up of digits, return it as a string.
        if (0 === preg_match('/\d+/', $item)) {
            return $item;
        }

        // else, cast to int.
        return intval($item);
    },
    explode(";", $var[0])
);
```

Comment: To elaborate on "not clear", a more precise phrasing might be: "more ambiguous than asking for the integer value of a string comprised entirely of numeric characters".

Comment: Array should be [0]=> 57 [1] => 5 [2] => 7 [3] => Hertha BSC - SV Werder Bremen is that possible? Maybe one array for int and another for the string value?

Comment: If you `var_dump`'d the (now badly named) `$int_array` var in my example, that's what you'd get! It only uses `intval` on the exploded array item if it's made entirely out of digits (`/\d+/`). Strings get left alone.